# sending multiples variables values to naxt page by URL

Tags: php, url

i am sending id and name field to next page through url . but it is contineously giving me error on the  url line . i tried alot  and use different ways  to resolve the issue but i did'nt . kindly help me out from this issue and give me a appropriate solution. it will be so grateful to you:

```
   $cityid=$nRow1['cty_id'];
   $cty_name=$nRow1['cty_name'];

    <li><a href="show_adlist.php?cty_id="<?php .$cityid."&cty_name=".$cty_name;?>>Search    Ads in </li>
```

Comment: You tried a lot of different ways but didn't think to look up basic PHP syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="show_adlist.php?cty_id="+<?php echo $cityid; ?>+"&cty_name="+<?php echo $cty_name;?>+" >Search    Ads in </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding echo. Also make sure you end the php code after cty_name.

```
$cityid=$nRow1['cty_id'];
$cty_name=$nRow1['cty_name'];

?>

<li><a href="show_adlist.php?cty_id="<?php echo $cityid."&cty_name=".$cty_name; ?>">Search    Ads in </li>
```